# How to animate CAShapeLayer path and fillColor

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, cgpath, cashapelayer

How to animate CAShapeLayer path and fillColor?

How to animate strokeEnd to show the path being drawn? and how to animate fillColor?

Comment: It animates automatically when you set it. Can you give a bit more information about what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To animate path

```
  //setup the CAShapeLayer
myShapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
myShapeLayer.lineWidth = 5;
myShapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];



//Display it!
[self.view.layer addSublayer:myShapeLayer];

//Animate path
CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 1.5f;
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
pathAnimation.repeatCount = 10;
pathAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
[myShapeLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];

//Animate colorFill
CABasicAnimation *fillColorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"fillColor"];
fillColorAnimation.duration = 1.5f;
fillColorAnimation.fromValue = (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
fillColorAnimation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];
fillColorAnimation.repeatCount = 10;
fillColorAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
[myShapeLayer addAnimation:fillColorAnimation forKey:@"fillColor"];
```

I hope this helps :)

**2021 Update**

**Swift**

```
    myShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
myShapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
myShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor

//Display it!
view.layer.addSublayer(myShapeLayer)

//Animate path
let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
pathAnimation.duration = 1.5
pathAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0.0)
pathAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1.0)
pathAnimation.repeatCount = 10
pathAnimation.autoreverses = true
myShapeLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")


//Animate colorFill
let fillColorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
fillColorAnimation.duration = 1.5
fillColorAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.clear.cgColor
fillColorAnimation.toValue = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
fillColorAnimation.repeatCount = 10
fillColorAnimation.autoreverses = true
myShapeLayer.add(fillColorAnimation, forKey: "fillColor")
```

Comment: I would add that fromValue and toValue could be CGMutablePathRef objects to animate changing the path itself, using key @"path". The above with that change worked for my purposes. Thanks.