# How to animate a drawn line in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath, cgpoint, uianimation, cashapelayer

I am trying to animate drawn objects, for example I have drawn a line with this approach:

```
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(Center.x, Center.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(Point.x,Point.y)];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.5;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

After a while I need to animate the line to have a different `Point`, but keeping `Center` as is, but I have no idea how to do that. Is my approach alright? Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to animate CAShapeLayer path and fillColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651717/how-to-animate-cashapelayer-path-and-fillcolor)

Comment: That is animating the drawing of the path, not animating it AFTER it's already drawn (which is what I am trying to achieve).
Thanks though! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it:

```
    CABasicAnimation *morph = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    morph.duration = 1.0;
    UIBezierPath *path5 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path5 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(P22.x+5, P22.y+5)];
    [path5 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(P21.x,P21.y)];
    morph.fromValue = (id) path.CGPath;
    morph.toValue = (id) path5.CGPath;

    [shapeLayer addAnimation:morph forKey:nil];

    //next line to update the shapeLayer's new path
    shapeLayer.path = path5.CGPath;
```

Comment: what is path here ?(fromValue) I have added same code but not get animation