# Animate UIView to disappear

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, core-graphics, core-animation

I currently have a UIView in Swift that has a background colour of red and a black outline with a UILabel inside.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class AdventDoor: UIView
{
    @IBInspectable var shapeColor:UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    var width:CGFloat?



    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //Initilse UIView
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        //Create UILabel
        let dateLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (bounds.width-25)-5, y: 3, width: 25, height: 20))
        dateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        dateLabel.text = self.restorationIdentifier!
        //Show the UILabel
        self.addSubview(dateLabel)

    }


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let drect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
        let bpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: drect)

        shapeColor.setFill()
        bpath.lineWidth = 5
        bpath.fill()
        bpath.stroke()
    }
}
```

Note: UIView may not show the design on the StoryBoard. To see the @IBDesignable you need to comment out the init function.

How would I animate the fill colour of the UILabel to close like sliding doors? I do not want the outline (`stroke`) to change width but I do want the inside to move?

This is what I want to happen:

Currently my UIView looks like this

[image]

What I want it to look like in the end is this

[image]

And in the middle of the animation I would like it to look like this

[image]

How would I achieve such animation using Core Graphics (or any other Library if needed)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651717/how-to-animate-cashapelayer-path-and-fillcolor

Comment: @Shubhank Could you make a post explaining it a bit more please? Also that is in Objective-C and not Swift 2.

Comment: yup, i wont be able to port it to swift without writing code in IDE and testing it. I gave it you as a pointer for further help. If you are proficient in both you might be able to port it, or maybe come and hang around in the chat and i can guide better. Cant really give full time to post a proper solution sorry as i have some other work.

Comment: @Shubhank Thanks. How do I start a chat with you so you can give me a better guid? I would also try to port it, but I don't understand the Objective-C code so that won't work!

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Shubhank Here is the link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96056/uiview-animation